# How to parse a XML file with Command Line (cmd/batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, xml-parsing

I have a XML file `Testing.Config` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="name1" connectionString="user id=id1;password=password1;"/>
    <add name="name2" connectionString="user id=id2;password=password2;"/>
    <add name="name3" connectionString="user id=id3;password=password3;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I need parse this file and obtain `id` and `password` key-value pairs in an attribute of a particular tag identified by the provided attribute, for example `"name=name1"`.

#### Example

Input:

```
 name=name1
```

Returns:

```
 id=id1
 password=password1
```

Comment: Is Unix* like shell is OK ?

Comment: Windows batch (.cmd)

Comment: Almost every version of windows has powershell.. consider doing it in powershell instead?

Comment: @Vikas Gupta. Yes, can be with both options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off

set "xml_file=test.xml"
set /p search_for=Enter name:

for /f "skip=2 tokens=3,9 delims=;= " %%a in ('find """%search_for%""" "%xml_file%"') do (

    set "name=%%~a"
    set "pass=%%b"
)

echo name : %name%
echo pass : %pass%
```

If all connectionStrings are on separated lines and every string is on one line.Change the location of the `xml_file`

---

You can also try the [**xpath.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat) (better option according to me)  -small script that will allow you to get a xml  values by xpath expression without using external binaries:

```
call xpath.bat connection.xml "//add[@name = 'name1']/@connectionString"
```

Comment: Is exactly what I wanted...
Only a change: tokens=3,9
It should be: tokens=7,9
Because I need the value of ID

Thank you!!!

Comment: Change: set /p search_for=Enter name:, by set /p "search_for=Enter name:". And """%search_for%""", by "%search_for%"

Answer (score 1):

Since you indicated (in comments on the question) that powershell is also okay, put the following code in a script file (lets say `Foo.ps1`)

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $ConfigFilePath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $Name
)

([xml](Get-Content -LiteralPath $ConfigFilePath)).connectionStrings.add |
Where-Object {$_.name -eq $name} |
ForEach-Object {($_.connectionString -split ' ')[1] -split ';'}
```

and then run the script with parameters to get the output.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes looking for this like I did... the **xpath.bat** linked by npocmaka works great, but not for file one network paths e.g. \server\foo\bar.xml. And I couldn't get Vikus's PS script to work for attributes. So... I managed to turn Vikus's PS into this:

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $XMLFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $Xpath
)
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $XMLFile
$value = Select-XML -xml $xml -xpath $Xpath
$value.ToString()
```

Which I then collapsed to this for use in a .cmd file:

```
set psc="(Select-XML -xml ([xml](Get-Content -Path %xmlfile%)) -xpath %xpath%).ToString()"
for /f %%a in ('powershell %psc%') do set myvar=%%a
```

Though it's worth noting that neither %xmlfile% nor %xpath% can have spaces. That requires escaping all the parentheses so that the powershell command doesn't have to be wrapped in double quotes:

```
for /F %a in ('powershell ^(Select-XML -xml ^([xml]^(Get-Content -Path "test.xml"^)^) -xpath "/Computers/Computer/Name/@id"^).ToString^(^)') do @echo %a
```

FWIW, they're all markedly slower that my original fragile monster:

```
@for /F eol^=^#^tokens^=2^,5^,7^ delims^=^<^>^" %%i in (%xmlfile%) do @(
    @if "%targetnodename% ATTR1=" == "%%i" (
        set myvar1=%%j
        set myvar1=%%k
    )
)
```